# Force terminal emulator to read .bash_logout (or .logout, etc)

Tags: linux, terminal, emulator, logout, terminal-emulator

*Searching fails me.*

I noticed that some terminal emulators (gnome-terminal, terminator, maybe others) do not execute my logout file.  Works well enough in a virtual terminal, but not through the emulators.

I looked at the man pages (of the emulators), but there seems to be no option to force the execution of a logout file.

Is it possible?

Comment: These files are not for terminals or terminal emulators. They are for shells. Please read [*What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618) The difference you observed is because terminal emulators tend to run [non-logins shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/108618) because you're already logged in (to Gnome, KDE or whatever), while in tty2 you *do* log in. What are you trying to achieve with `.logout`? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right about all that.  In my situation I rarely log out of X, and my terminal sessions all have timeouts.  My logout process simply runs `ponysay`; I just like to see the art before deciding what to do with the terminal.  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the bash manual:

> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists.

So `bash_logout` executes when a *login* shell exits. It may be the case that the emulators are not opening a login shell, there could be configurations you can change on the client to make sure it loads a login shell everytime.

Alternatively you can open a new shell with `-l` or `--login` and that will load a login shell for you.

Comment: I totally forgot about the option of "Run command as a login shell" or passing those sort of arguments over, ie for terminator `--execute bash -l`.  Thanks for the reminder!